# Xcode render the .PNG images all white

Tags: xcode, png, transparency

I'm importing a .PNG into xcode. The image has transparency. When it's rendered on a button from the ID, all the content of the image except the transparency turns to white.

Is this a known issue? Is it because of the way I save the .PNG?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the .png look correct when viewing it elsewhere (such as Preview)? If you post your relevant code, it might be easier to spot the issue.

Comment: Wait a minute - are you talking about UIButton or UIBarButtonItem? It sound like the latter... does the image show properly if you load it into a UIImageView?

Comment: yes, the image looks just fine in the preview (before importing the image in xcode), but not in the interface builder, where I set the image on the button properties

Comment: Yes, it is a UIBarButtonItem and it does display correctly if it's UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

To display an image in a UIBarButtonItem, you need to create a UIButton with the image, then add that button to the UIBarButtonItem.  Otherwise you just get the outline, as you mentioned.

So:

```
// Initialize the UIButton with your image
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someImage" ofType:@"png"]];
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Then create the UIBarButton
UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how images work on UIBarButtonItems and UITabBarItems: the image you supply is only used as a transparency mask. You can either use an UIImageView/UIButton instead to display your image (as AtkinsonCM has suggested), or create an image that will work as a mask.

I personally feel it's usually better to play by Apple's rules, unless you have a compelling reason not to (e.g. the user experience will be significantly improved).